# Android URL IOException

Tags: java, android

Ok i'm trying this Call:

```
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> httpParams;

    httpParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender", gender));

    try {
        SERVICE_URL = new URL("http://idea-app.net/android/com/ProjectCaruso/Idea/SaveUser.php");

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.i(Utils.TAG, "Login Async: MalformedURLException: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    String response = doUrlPost(SERVICE_URL, httpParams);
```

Here is the code it calls:

```
public String doUrlPost(URL url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> httpParams) {

    if (url != null) {
        String response = "";

        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getQuery(httpParams));
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            conn.connect();

            //start listening to the stream
            Scanner inStream = new Scanner(conn.getInputStream());

            //process the stream and store it in StringBuilder
            while(inStream.hasNextLine())
            response+=(inStream.nextLine());

        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.i(Utils.TAG, "Login Async: ProtocolException: " + e.toString());
        }
         catch (IOException e) {
             Log.i(Utils.TAG, "Login Async: IOException: " + e.toString());
        }

        return response;
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}

public String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params)
    {
        if (pair.getValue() == null) {
            Log.i(Utils.TAG, "Push Data: Null value pair for: " + pair.getName());
        } else {

            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");
                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
                result.append("=");
                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
                }
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Here's the error:

```
02-12 09:37:49.366: I/PROJECTCARUSO(29457): Login Async: IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://idea-app.net/android/com/ProjectCaruso/Idea/SaveUser.php
02-12 09:37:49.366: W/System.err(29457): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://idea-app.net/android/com/ProjectCaruso/Idea/SaveUser.php
02-12 09:37:49.366: W/System.err(29457):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
02-12 09:37:49.366: W/System.err(29457):    at com.projectCaruso.idea.LoginAsyncTask.doUrlPost(LoginAsyncTask.java:108)
02-12 09:37:49.366: W/System.err(29457):    at com.projectCaruso.idea.LoginAsyncTask.doInBackground(LoginAsyncTask.java:69)
02-12 09:37:49.366: W/System.err(29457):    at com.projectCaruso.idea.LoginAsyncTask.doInBackground(LoginAsyncTask.java:1)
02-12 09:37:49.366: W/System.err(29457):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-12 09:37:49.366: W/System.err(29457):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-12 09:37:49.366: W/System.err(29457):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-12 09:37:49.366: W/System.err(29457):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-12 09:37:49.376: W/System.err(29457):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-12 09:37:49.376: W/System.err(29457):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://idea-app.net/android/com/ProjectCaruso/Idea/SaveUser.php

Comment: Thank you, that is blatantly obvious that that's the error its throwing but the url does exists.

Comment: Do you have the internet permission?

Comment: yes `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See in your LogCat:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://idea-app.net/android/com/ProjectCaruso/Idea/SaveUser.php
```

this url really exists?
http://idea-app.net/android/com/ProjectCaruso/Idea/SaveUser.php

Comment: Ok i haven´t saw the comments, this question was solved.

Comment: I think you misunderstood Elenasys, the url exists but doesn't do anything when you go to it because its php and dies if you haven't passed in values it needs. Thus the empty page. I was telling Tyler that because all he did was quote the log cat which is neither helpful or explained. It is as i fear he is... worthless.